# How to do I ssh to another machine with another user to execute a script

Tags: bash, ssh

Synopsis:

```
[user1]$ whoami   
         user1

[user1]$ vi someScript.sh 

#!/bin/sh 
echo "Hello World!"

[user1]$ chmod 777 someScript.sh 

[user1]$ ls -l

        xrw-xrw-xrw someScript.sh

[user1]$ ssh user2@remoteMachine /home/user1/someScript.sh

**Problem Area** 

[user1]$

  Permission denied
```

**Desired Result**

To perform this type of execution from a different user. How do I do this?

This is a NFS file system. user1 and user2 can see each others files

Comment: scp /home/user1/someScript.sh user2@remoteMachine: ; ssh user2@remoteMachine /home/user2/someScript.sh

Comment: @Oliver no need to scp they are on the same NFS network.

Comment: So "ssh user2@remoteMachine ls /home/user1/someScript.sh" works? If not, check the home directory permissions. If it is NFS, there might also be an auto-mounter in play which hasn't mounted user1's home directory on the remote machine yet.

Comment: @Oliver this doesn't work for some reason. Even when I open full permission to the script, I still get permissions denied. It should already be mounted

Answer (score 1):

If you script does not refer to $0 or any argument variables, you can do it this way

```
  ssh user2@remoteMachine bash <  ./someScript.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your /home partition on remotehost is mounted with the "noexec" option, you can check that in /etc/fstab

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user2 has access to the home of user - exactly as you did. Otherwise user2 has to get access to the files of user1, and specifically: get the permission to execute on that script. Or at least to read it, so it can be executed with `sh .../script.sh`.

Comment: I opened permissions wide open as I demonstrated above. I dont know why I'm still getting permissions denied

Comment: Not to the directory /home/user1, as seen from remoteMachine. Does `ssh user@remote ls -ld /home/user1` give something interesting?

Comment: Still permissions denied with ssh user@remote ls -ld /home/user1

Comment: try going up: `ssh user@remote ls -ld /home`, and check if you can do anything on that machine `ssh user@remote uname -a`. And please post complete error text

Comment: Do you need to have appropriate permission set in the base directory to allow `others` execute stuff  where the script resides?

Comment: Yes, of course. Try setting 0000 permissions on /usr directory and run anything from /usr/bin

Comment: Er... That last was a joke. Seems like a stupid one, too. I just hope you're still around